# Gsuite Marketplace publish process: 404 error

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace

Looking into building some Gsuite Marketplace apps, but we have having issues at the publish time already.

1. Publishing an app following [these steps](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/overview) makes the app to be accessible from the Chrome Marketplace.
   (e.g. `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/qwertzuiopasdfghjkl/publish-accepted`)
2. Using Chrome web store app link (e.g. `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/app-name/qwertzuiopasdfghjkl`)
   redirects to a Gsuite link (e.g. `https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/qwertzuiopasdfghjkl?pann=cwsdp&hl=en-US`) but brings a 404 page.
3. Waiting seems to do the job (url works after a couple of days - approval)
4. Changing app type from "Private" to "Unlisted" break it completely; even waiting up to a week, the link never works again.

My questions are:

- How do you switch between "Visibility options" without breaking your
  app?
- How do you guys deal with updating publishing apps on Gsuite
  Marketplace and keep it working?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Every new update requires a new installation. So everytime you make changes whether feature or visibility settings, treat it as if you were uploading a new app.

If you change the visibility, it will undergo a review process as if it were a new app.

Users who have already installed your app will still be able to use it.